# How to reset interrupted flag in executorservice.invokeAll()

Tags: java, executorservice

I've learnt that it is the good practice to set Thread.interrupter() flag back to `true` after catching a InterruptedException.

However when I call `executorService.invokeAll()` and put a try clause around it, by catching the InterruptedException, will `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` correctly flag the interrupted thread, or the main thread of my controller/runner?

```
public class Controller {

    public void run() {

        final List<Task> tasks = request.collectTasks()

        try {
            executorService.invokeAll(tasks);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            message = "interrupted";
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            throw new InternalFailureException(message);
        }
    }
}

class Task implements Callable<String> {
      @Override
      public String call() {
          return taskId;
      }
}
```

Overall is this the correct way to reset the interrupted flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code example you have given

```
try {
       executorService.invokeAll(tasks);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        message = "interrupted";
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        throw new InternalFailureException(message);
    }
```

whoever invokes `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` will set the flag of that thread in this example it will be the thread executing your `Controller#run()` method.

Ideally with executors it is the responsibility of `Task` or `Runnable` which gets scheduled over the executor to handle this flag properly.

Since it is a checked exception already - it will not give you an opportunity to decorate the task that you are about to submit inside executor so you have no easy control over it.